# Copy input when click

Tags: javascript, select, copy

I want to copy input when I click it, but I want make it like variable for use the same function for copy other input.

```js
function copyToClipboard(here) {
  var textBox = document.getElementById(here);
  textBox.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="myvalue" id="myvalue" value="YEAH" readonly />
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="copyToClipboard(myvalue);">Copy myvalue</button>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you format your code for readability and elaborate on specifically what isn't working?  Note: Formatting your code for readability immediately reveals a structural problem.  Converting it into a runnable snippet and running it immediately reveals a syntax error.  Perhaps this was just a typo on your part?

Comment: @yazan I have answered your question, you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed all the basic javascript fundamentals, you need to just change your javascript function. 
Read some basic javascript properly

```js
   function copyToClipboard(here) {
       var textBox = here;
       textBox.select();
       document.execCommand("copy");
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="myvalue"  id="myvalue" value="YEAH" readonly  />
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="copyToClipboard(myvalue);">Copy myvalue</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you , it is just not my language , and i need it so start learn it